# UPDATE RECORD 2 FIRST LATTER IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

How do you update the record in the first 2 letters as in the case below.

TABLE `tblBuku`

[image: 1]

This is the condition

[image: 2]

Some Code :

```
UPDATE tblBuku SET Jenis = 'Informatika' WHERE NoBuku(2) = 'IF';
```

Comment: Are you looking at first two letters or last two letters?  Your question says ` last 2 letters` but the examples have first two letters.

Comment: Please **edit** and clarify your requirement; I assume you want the final two *letters* (not the final two *characters*) checked in the SQL?

Comment: Questions here cannot include screenshots of text. Everything required to answer your question has to go in your question as human- and machine-readable text.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I've edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For LAST two letters:**

```
UPDATE tblBuku SET Jenis = 'Informatika' WHERE NoBuku LIKE '%IF'
```

or

```
UPDATE tblBuku SET Jenis = 'Informatika' WHERE RIGHT(NoBuku , 2) = 'IF'
```

**For FIRST two letters:**

```
UPDATE tblBuku SET Jenis = 'Informatika' WHERE NoBuku LIKE 'IF%'
```

or

```
UPDATE tblBuku SET Jenis = 'Informatika' WHERE LEFT(NoBuku , 2) = 'IF'
```

**Explanation**

- `%` is a wildcard.  It indicates one of more of any character.
- `RIGHT` and `LEFT` get the substring
  `LEFT(field_name, number of characters to extract from the left)`

Comment: The vote count just changed to 0 but no vote summary or vote count is being shown.  SO bug or something.

Answer (score 1):

This will replace all your rows, taking consideration the value for every case. It won't replace if the value doesn't match with the cases. Be aware.

```
UPDATE tblBuku 
SET Jenis = 
(
CASE
 WHEN (LEFT(NoBuku, 2) = 'IF') THEN 'Informatika'
  WHEN (LEFT(NoBuku, 2) = 'EL') THEN 'Eletronika'
 WHEN (LEFT(NoBuku, 2) = 'MT') THEN 'Matematika'
END
)
```